# Validacion Jquery y Animacion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-validate

Quiero realizar la validación de este formulario, pero solo logro que muestre los mensajes de validación apretando el botón siguiente; no estoy encontrando de que manera lograr la validación y que impida seguir interactuando con los elementos del formulario, así mismo evitar que se sigan pintando los círculos al apretar siguiente.

Ya que es bastante código, dejo mi codepen. https://codepen.io/kamp3r/pen/XWgEKvB

Esta es mi función de formulario para avanzar las páginas y pintar círculos:

```
$("#formSimulador").on("click", function(e){
  let boton = e.target;
  let botonAtras = $(boton).hasClass("anteriorButton")
  let botonAdelante = $(boton).hasClass("siguienteButton")
  if (botonAtras || botonAdelante){
    let pasoActual = $('#paso-' + boton.dataset.paso);
    let pasoSiguiente =  $('#paso-' + boton.dataset.al_paso)
    pasoActual.toggleClass('active');
    pasoSiguiente.toggleClass('active');
    if (botonAdelante){
      actualmenteActivo++;
      if(actualmenteActivo > circulos.length){
        actualmenteActivo = circulos.length;
      }else if(actualmenteActivo > icons.lenght){
        actualmenteActivo = icons.length;
      }
      actualizarBarra();
      pasoActual.addClass('animacionIzq');
      if(!$('#formSimulador').valid()) return false;
    } else if(botonAtras){
      actualmenteActivo--;
      if(actualmenteActivo < 1){
        actualmenteActivo = 1;
      }
      actualizarBarra();
      pasoSiguiente.removeClass('animacionIzq')
    };
  };
  })
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.